# prove $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2\lt\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-a)^2$

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, means

How do we prove that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2\lt\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-a)^2
$$

where $a$ is any value other than $\bar{x}$, the arithmetic mean.

**My Attempt:**
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i^2-2x_i\bar{x}+\bar{x}^2)\lt\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i^2-2x_ia+a^2)\\\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2-2\bar{x}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\bar{x}^2\lt\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2-2a\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^2\\-2\bar{x}.n\bar{x}+n.\bar{x}^2\lt-2a.n\bar{x}+n.a^2\\-2\bar{x}^2+\bar{x}^2\lt-2a\bar{x}+a^2\\-\bar{x}^2\lt-2a\bar{x}+a^2
$$
But how do I proceed further or is there any better way ?

Comment: Sure you have no idea to show that $$\bar{x}^2-2a\bar{x}+a^2\geqslant0\ ?$$

Comment: @Did ohh thnx.. i got into trouble thinking about either $\bar{x}>a$ or $\bar{x}<a$, tht was a stupid question.

Comment: Just building on what you wrote, like in this tale about the bird who could fly the highest...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

consider $$f(a) \equiv\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-a)^2 $$

so that 
$$f'(a) =-2\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-a) =-2n(\bar x -a) $$
so $f(a)$ is minimized when $a=\bar x$

Answer (score 3):

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-a)^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}((x_i-a)^2-(x_i-\bar{x})^2)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}((x_i-a)-(x_i-\bar{x}))((x_i-a)+(x_i-\bar{x}))\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\bar{x}-a)(2x_i-(a+\bar{x}))\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\bar{x}-a)(2x_i)-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\bar{x}-a)(a+\bar{x})\\
&=2(\bar{x}-a)\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n(\bar{x}^2-a^2)\\
&=2(\bar{x}-a)n\bar{x}-n(\bar{x}^2-a^2)\\
&=2n\bar{x}^2-2an\bar{x}-n\bar{x}^2+na^2\\
&=n\bar{x}^2-2an\bar{x}+na^2\\
&=n(\bar{x}^2-2a\bar{x}+a^2)\\
&=n(\bar{x}-a)^2\\
&\ge 0\\
\end{array}
$

with equality only if
$a = \bar{x}$.

Answer (score 2):

It would be simpler to think this as a quadratic function of $a$:
$$
f(a) = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-a)^2 = A a^2 + B a + C,
$$
where
$$
A = n, \quad B = -2 \sum_{i=1}^n x_i, \quad\text{and}\quad C = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2.
$$
"Completing the square" shows that for $A > 0$ the parabola $f(a)$ is minimized at $a = -B/(2A)$.  Substituting the values above yields a minimum at $a = \bar{x}$.

Answer (score 2):

By factoring the difference of squares and taking the means (proportional to the sums),

$$\overline{(x_i-\overline x)^2-(x_i-a)^2}=\overline{(x_i-\overline x+x_i-a)}\overline{(a-\overline x)}=(\overline x-\overline x+\overline x-a)(a-\overline x)<0.$$

Comment: Essentially the same as mine, but simpler. I would add $=-(a-\bar{x})^2$ before the final inequality. Also, if $a=\bar{x}$ there is equality.

Comment: I was working it out as I went, so all the steps were necessary. I could remove some lines, but I like to leave in all steps.

Comment: @martycohen By hypothesis, $a\ne\overline x$.

Comment: That hypothesis is unnecessary. The algebra shows that the difference is $n(a-\bar{x})^2$ which gives the condition for equality.

Comment: @martycohen: the hypothesis is not mine. I am answering the question in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have gotten the last intequality, just note that $$-\bar{x}^2<-2a\bar{x}+a^2\iff \bar{x}^2 -2a\bar{x}+a^2\iff(\bar{x}-a)^2>0.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $a \neq \bar{x}$,

$$(a-\bar{x})^2 >0$$

$$a^2+\bar{x}^2-2a\bar{x}>0$$

$$-\bar{x}^2<a^2-2a\bar{x}$$

Comment: And? ..........

Comment: read his proof from the end to the beginning.